# How many retags should you do before asking a moderator?

Tags: discussion, tags

Assuming you are doing a routine tag fix that doesn't require discussion...

How many posts should someone re-tag en masse (which bumps messages in the `active` tab) before asking a moderator to use their non-bumping, tag-renaming super powers?

Comment: My personal record is around forty, I think. That gets tedious - especially on a browser that isn't terribly fast at rendering.

Comment: @mmyers - I've done the mass-question re-tag manually. But my Q is how many *should* you do before it becomes front-page spam/annoying. Just looking for a general consensus.

Comment: You should definitely ask a question, if there may be some disagreement on how the questions should be tagged.

Comment: @Brad Gilber - This post refers to "routine" retags, requiring *no* discussion. I.e., re-re-retags of past `retag-request`s that need to be fixed again, mis-typed tags ([for][loop] > [for-loop]), etc.

Comment: I just did 68. I'm not going to do that again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say at whatever point posting the request here on meta becomes less work than manually retagging the posts.  Somewhere around 10 but less than 20 is my rough guesstimate.  Any more than that would definitely draw complaints that the tag was being spammed (which I know from past experience).

Comment: i think my tedium tolerance tends to tolerate twenty to thirty.  (alliteration ftw!) beyond that it's retag-requestin' time.

Comment: @~quack: +1 for amazing alliterative acumen!

Comment: Good to have a metric of when re-tagging generates "complaints," straight from the <strike>horse's</strike> Lizard's mouth.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should worry about question bumping, it would probably do them good to see the light of day one last time.

Answer (score 1):

For myself, I wouldn't think twice about 10, but would probably balk at 50.