# Ignoring retagged old questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, bump

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [It should be possible to retag a question without bumping it to the front page.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29394/it-should-be-possible-to-retag-a-question-without-bumping-it-to-the-front-page)
>   [Too much retagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46205/too-much-retagging)
>   [Retagging/Bumping Etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51767/retagging-bumping-etiquette)

Don Stewart is currently going through a lot of *old* Haskell questions and retagging them. Nothing wrong with that, but they show up on the home page rather pointlessly. Shouldn't they be ignored, especially as many of them have an accepted answer?

Comment: [To paraphrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy), many solutions were suggested for this problem, but this one is not concerned with the movements of small green pieces of paper: [System to minimize the soft problems due to manual retagging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46729).