# Please merge "ast" and "abstract-syntax-tree" tags

Tags: support, retag-request

I think [abstract-syntax-tree](/questions/tagged/abstract-syntax-tree) should be the master tag for [ast](/questions/tagged/ast)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this yourself, providing you have enough rep.  Which [if this is you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter) then you do.

Retag all the questions from `ast` to `abstract-syntax-tree`
Then propose a new synonym to convert all further questions tagged `ast` are automatically converted to `abstract-syntax-tree`.

**UPDATE:**

AS Roger has pointed out, a Diamond Moderator will be able to merge these tags for you as there are a fair few questions to be re-tagged.

Comment: There are 50 [ast] and 46 [abstract-syntax-tree].  Manual merges are *discouraged* for that many.  Diamond moderators can rename these tags with a single click and no noise on the homepage.  However, we can use [synonyms](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ast/synonyms) for that now, and they can merge after it's voted in.

Comment: @Roger - Didn't realise they are discouraged.  Each time I have asked it has been a case of DIY.

Comment: @Barry: For low numbers, but I can't recall anyone saying about 50 is close to low enough in normal circumstances.

Comment: @Roger - Fair enough.  I seem to remember re-tagging about 25-30 or so a while back.  Now I'm pretty sure I wasted my time :-)  Cheers

Comment: @Barry: Thanks for that effort anyway! If you have 2k, you can vote for the synonym, which seems to be how things will play out more often from here on out.

Comment: Gah, you include the update and I remove my downvote to have someone add another... but anyway, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38987/how-many-retags-should-you-do-before-asking-a-moderator

Comment: @Roger - ah well such is life! Thanks anyway - I have kept a record of that link for future.

Comment: All: I've manually retagged probably a dozen tags since joining SO. Early in SO's life, there were often only a handful and doing it manually seemed... OK. 20 is about the point where I lose patience; there's 50+ "ast" tags. Glad to hear somebody might do it en masse, which is the reason for the polite "retag-request".