# Can the [star] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

There's a tag: [star](/questions/tagged/star) which I think needs to be removed. It has no wiki, so there's no good way to tell why it was created, but its usage is inconstant and not relevant:

[20 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stars) are tagged with [star](/questions/tagged/star); they break down as:

- 4 question about astronomy-related program (position of a celestial body)
- 7 question regarding quality ('star' ratings)
- 2 question about a "star-field" (background image, or opengl star patterns)
- 4 question about printing the ASCII asterisk character in a pattern (called "star" by OP)
- 1 question about gmail's "starring" emails for later reference
- 1 question about google's "started" locations on maps
- 1 question about "stars" [graphics in R](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/graphics/stars)

The only one programming-related is R's graphic function, but I don't think we need a tag for one question. The highest one "star ratings" are all also tagged with [rating](/questions/tagged/rating), and the celestial body questions are also tagged with [astronomy](/questions/tagged/astronomy); so it seems the [star](/questions/tagged/star) isn't doing any good.

Comment: With only 20 questions you don't need help: edit out all usages and [it will soon be purged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83171)

Comment: @AakashM - I just wanted to see if there is any dispute with it before doing so. When taking actions which affect the community, I like to make sure the community is aware of it. :)

Comment: The Unanswered tab count strikes again; there are actually 71 star questions