# Inspecting a user activity after an edit flood

Tags: support, recent-activity, serial-edits

How can I properly review a large amount of edits from one user? Clicking on 50 arrows to check that all of the edits are ok is not my idea of fun. Is there a way to pre-expand all the arrows? Can I get one page with all the edits, instead of 3?

[image: added new tag ×20]

Comment: If 5 suggestions are rejected in a row, the user will get auto banned from suggesting any further edits for 7 days afaik isn't that enough?

Comment: Needs more jQuery?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Suggested? Who said anything about suggested edits? This is a user with more than 500 rep.

Comment: Oh sorry - didn't notice.

Comment: Those are all tag edits.  If you inspect a random sample of them, you should get a pretty fair idea if he's using the tag system correctly.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd That might be fine if the user didn't have edit privileges. Those were edits, not suggestions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have a good idea of what *most* of his edits are. I'm asking for a way of checking that these are the only edits he made.

Comment: If it says "Added New Tag" and doesn't say "Added/removed n characters" then the tag edits are the only change.

Comment: @RobertHarvey [Pfft!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/130254/revisions) that doesn't mean squat. Also, if you edit tags first, then change your mind and do some more edits within the 5 min grace period, then the previous edit message still holds and is not updated.

Comment: Looks like someone is digging for the Taxonomist badge. Maybe someone should tell this [user to have a talk with the mods first](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38987/how-many-retags-should-you-do-before-asking-a-moderator), otherwise [the work might be reversed](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/837/many-hours-of-work-on-tags-reverted-without-discussion-moderator-abusing-their).

Comment: Well, I take my taxonomist-badge-comment back after seeing those edits myself...but I can not comment on the usefulness of those edits, either...

Comment: Another problem is that fetching those summaries is limited to one every second.