# Retagging questions to its parent language if possible

Tags: support, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

My personal favorite tag is [android](/questions/tagged/android) and I noticed the emphasis on [using android(language) specific tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info)..

My concern is [edittext](/questions/tagged/edittext), for which  99% of pages are also tagged [android](/questions/tagged/android). I tried to do some retagging, but there are way too many. I did go through [How many retags should you do before asking a moderator?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38996/221351) before getting complaints of spamming.

So I guess retagging all of them won't be easy without moderator tools.

I do have the [Create tag synonym privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) but I am unsure how that works. Moreover I need to have at least 5 scores in these tags to act upon them.

So,

- can we retag all [edittext](/questions/tagged/edittext) to [android-edittext](/questions/tagged/android-edittext) which also has [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag in question  using
  awesome Mod tools,
- Or create a tag synonym (Don't know how that will work because there are few
  question not tagged as Android)
- Can we give a **gentle reminder** to the OP about using specific tag if
  also marked with master tag while posting the question itself.

Comment: Mass-retagging a bunch of questions that fit a certain rule would come in handy in many situations, but I don't think it's ever been done before.

Comment: @slhck exactly, I guess my 3rd point of *gentle reminder* will help to avoid such situations.. And moderators can retag them all in their powers.. Right??

Comment: Is there any `edittext` question that shouldn't be changed to `android-edittext`?  Are there other contexts for `edittext` besides android?  If the answer to both is no, then it should be a tag synonym.  If yes, then it's complicated...

Comment: Don't use "b'coz".

Comment: @Servy yes, there are [few question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edittext+-android) tagged with c++ and delphi. I dont have much much knowledge about them..

Comment: @CRUSADER If there are very few, then the best bet would most likely be to manually change all question that shouldn't be `android-edittext` to something else (does `c++-edittext` make sense?) and then make the tag synonym to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the suggestion of [@Servy in commments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195765/retagging-questions-to-its-parent-language-if-possible#comment617327_195765).

Few tags created in the process they are as follows.

[c#-edittext](/questions/tagged/c%23-edittext)
[c++-edittext](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-edittext)
[php-edittext](/questions/tagged/php-edittext)
[gwt-edittext](/questions/tagged/gwt-edittext)
[blackberry-editfield](/questions/tagged/blackberry-editfield)

<sub>*please burninate these tags if you find these tags irrelevant or inappropriate.</sub>

There are now no questions with tags [[tag:edittext] and not [tag:android]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edittext+-android). So now we can safely make synonym of [android-edittext](/questions/tagged/android-edittext). So, *Mission Accomplished* a.k.a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Someone already suggested the same long back but in following order.

[edittext](/questions/tagged/edittext) ← [android-edittext](/questions/tagged/android-edittext)

From @comments reverse would have made more sense since hardly any questions that get tag ediitext and not android.
<sub>Irony,I have 5 score to support the tag synonymn but cant create reverse as I dont have 5 score in [edittext](/questions/tagged/edittext)</sub>

All said, tag clean up is done, proper retagging done.. :)